Translating Documents in Azure AI Translator
Can someone please point me to a good, easy-to-understand resource on how to get documents translated within Azure AI Translator? Ideally, a step-by-step instruction video. Thanks!
The Azure AI interface is incredibly cumbersome, hard to understand, and most online resources for navigating it are out-of-date and/or incorrect. I have not found any resources at Microsoft helpful.

Here, firstly you need to have a resource so, go to azure portal and search for translator resource.

Click on create and provide the required details like subscription and resource group name and resource name.

Enable managed identity for role assignments to get access.


Assign the below role that allows the user to give input and get the translated data.

Result:

We can also upload any text file, doc, or .mp4 file it will translate and provide as per the requirement.

Go to ai.azure.com and check for the AI services and click on it.


Click on document translator and create AI service resource. if you already having the resource, you can use it.

